# Vim Execute Nohlsearch Not Working in Function

Tags: vim

:)
I like to use search highlighting in *Vim*. But after a while it sucks and I've to remove it manually (mapping is defined). So I wrote a function to remove the highlighting after a while, bounded to an autocommand. Cause time could be a problem if u r just starring on the search result, I bound this function to the `CursorMoved` event and introduce a counter until zero. In case I jump between the results or decide to jump to a search result element later on, this works fine and all results are highlighted again (manually tested).

I inserted a lot of `echo` messages to track the behavior. It works absolutely fine until the counter "expires" (gets zero). Then the highlighting and counter should been removed. Both works as the `echo` output stated, but not visually. A check after unset highlight with `echom v:hlsearch` approve, that it has worked, but directly afterwards its highlighted again (delay not visible). So the loop begin again, cause the counter is expired, but a "new" highlighting is detected.
Calling the same command as in the function works perfeclty. So what happens?

So this is my code in the `.vimrc`:

```
" Function used if something is highlighted in the document.
" Is meant to be called several times by a autocommand.
" Sets a counter on the first call.
" Afterwards it decrease the counter each time get called, until zero.
" When the highlighting will be removed and the counter also.
" By this the time until remove highlighting depends on the frequency of
" function calls and that depend on the bounded auto command.
"
function! s:remove_highlight()
  echom 'Call'
  " Only makes sense when something is highlighted.
  if v:hlsearch
    echom 'In'
    " First call, so set the start time
    if !exists('g:highlight_counter')
      echom 'first call after new highlighting'
      let g:highlight_counter = 4

    else
      " Decrease highlight counter.
      let g:highlight_counter = g:highlight_counter - 1
      echom 'check ' . g:highlight_counter

      " Check if the counter is expired.
      if g:highlight_counter <= 0 
        " Unset counter and remove highlight.
        unlet g:highlight_counter
        execute 'nohlsearch'
        echom 'done? ' . !v:hlsearch
      else 
      endif
    endif

    echom 'out'
  endif

  echom 'End'
endfunction
```

Any ideas what happens here? I've no clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `:nohlsearch` is an ex command so you don't need that `:execute`.

Second, `:help :nohlsearch` says:

> This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because the highlighting state is saved and restored when executing autocommands |autocmd-searchpat|. **Same thing for when invoking a user function.**

So… you can't use it in a function.

Disabling search highlighting after a search is *not* trivial. If you want an idea of how involved it *actually* is I'd suggest taking a look at [the code of vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool/blob/master/plugin/cool.vim).

Answer (score 5):

Try this from inside the function:

```
call feedkeys( ":nohlsearch\<CR>" )
```

Note: mind the double quotes, they are needed for the escape sequence.  This works for me even from inside a function (tested with vim 8).  I'm not a vimscript expert, but what may be happening here is that it adds the keys into a queue and processes them only after the function finishes.

Comment: It must be `call feedkeys( ":set nohlsearch\<CR>" )`

Comment: Nice way to hack Vim.